# Switch focus between two visible viewControllers (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I currently have a viewController(#2) on top of another viewController(#1). ViewController is displayed as a little modal like in the picture below and has functionality completely separate from viewController 1.

The current focus (intractable UI) is on controller 2 because it is on top, but I want to interact with the content on controller 1 with controller 2 open. How do I shift focus between them so that I can interact with both interfaces interchangeably and keep both in view?

### [image]

ViewController 1 segues to viewController 2 by using "present modally" and viewController 2 is visible by setting presentation to "over current context".

Comment: Are you using `self.present` to show your second view controoler?

Comment: Yeah, I've set it in Storyboard as "present modally" which should be equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that because your second view controller is presented modally. It covers everything of your view controller 1 so that you cannot interact with it. If you really want user to interact with both part of your screen, you need to replace your view controller 2 with a `UIView`

If you really want to keep the second View controller, add a Container View to your storyboard and make a segue connection to your second view controller, like this
[image]

Comment: Thanks! A container view was exactly what I needed to keep both my controllers